# Center current cell view on datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, center

How can i center view on my selected current cell in datagridview?

For example i have datagridview like this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {

                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X" + i, "X" + i);
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 30;
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y" + i);
                //  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = "X";
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.HotPink;
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }


            for (int kolumna = 0; kolumna < 200; kolumna++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[kolumna].Cells[i].Value = "X";
                }
            }
```

It looks like :
[image]

How can i center the current selected cell in my datagridview?
I searched a lot and can't find solution.
For example i want to select  row/cell 100/100.

I try with

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[100,100];
```

But it only shows in right-down on my datagridview.

Result should be like this :
CELL [100/row100] centered on the view in datagridview.
Is it possible to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedrow - 9;
                dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = selectedcolumn - 15;
            }
            catch { };
        }
```

It makes all. This event center your datagrdivew when selected row is changed.